# How to use varying text alignment in a popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

Is it possible to use varying text alignment in a popup of this type, as taken from W3Schools How To (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp)?

This div section shows what I'd like to do with the popup text:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup
 <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
I'd Like to Center this Heading
<br><br>
Align-left this message.
<br><br>
And center this final prompt
</span>
</div>
```

---

And here is the original most pertinent CSS:

```
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 160px;
   background-color: #555;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 6px;
   padding: 8px 0;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   bottom: 125%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each text section should be separated into different containers that in turn will get different styles.

```css
.popup {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.popup-header,
.popup-footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.popup-body {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup
 <div class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
   <div class="popup-header">
     <span>I'd Like to Center this Heading</span>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-body">
      <span>Align-left this message.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-footer">
      <span>And center this final prompt</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your code, the entire text is inline in one single element, so it's impossible to change alignment to the different texts that way. You'll have to separate them, like I did with `popup-header`, `popup-body` and `popup-footer` CSS classes.

Comment: thank you very much, but the function call is to the popuptext id:
    <script> //When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
        var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
    </script>

Comment: I don't understand how your comment here is related to what you have asked above. How is the JS code relevant to the styling question?

Comment: I have edited my answer so it will follow the same logic you probably have in your JS function. Take a look at it again.

Comment: That is the answer, my friend! Thank you!